# View Names Disappeared

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm using STS 3.6.0 on Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit. It was working fine and now the view names (e.g. console, problems, search etc) have disappeared and I'm just left with the icons (see screenshot below). This has also happened with other views including the package explorer and also the file names in the text editor window.

[image]

I've tried removing STS 3.6.0 completely and installing v3.6.1 but get the same issue there.

Comment: I've never seen this before, but what shows up in the preferences when you try to change the font of the view titles? Does it have any effect?

Comment: Went to General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts. The font for View and Active Folders > Part Title font is Segoe UI. I've tried changing this but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just managed to resolve this. Under General > Appearance in Window > Preferences, the Eclipse/STS theme was set to Windows 7. I changed this to Classic and the view names returned.